# Outlets are duplicated post spartacus upgrade 6.0

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We have created our own component for ProductVariantStyleIconsComponent and injected through provideOutlet. It was working fine till version 5.2. Upon spartacus upgrade 6.2 this is duplicated.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    provideOutlet({
      id: ProductListOutlets.ITEM_DETAILS,
      position: OutletPosition.AFTER,
      component: CustomProductVariantStyleIconsComponent,
    }),
  ],
})
export class CustomProductVariantsRootModule {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, it may occur if the outlet configuration module is imported multiple times (either indirectly or directly) within the SpartacusFeaturesModule. the solution is to create a dedicated module for providing outlet configurations. Here's an example:

```js
// Module A 
@NgModule({
  imports: [...], // provideOutlet config was removed from this module
  declarations: [...],
  exports: [TestComponent],
})
export class ModuleA { }

// Module B
@NgModule({
  imports: [ModuleA],
})
export class ModuleB { }

// Module C
@NgModule({
  imports: [ModuleA],
})
export class ModuleC { }

// OutletConfigModule (Provide outlet configurations here)
@NgModule({
  imports: [ModuleA],
  providers: [
    provideOutlet({
      id: customOutlets.TEST,
      component: TestComponent,
    }),
  ]
})
export class OutletConfigModule { }

// Spartacus feature module
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleB, 
    ModuleC,
    OutletConfigModule // This line will create the TestComponent
  ],
})
export class SpartacusFeaturesModule { }
```

You can find a detailed description of the issue here: [GitHub Issue #17711](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/17711#issuecomment-1728888481)